# Remove space autocomplete from M-x

Tags: completion

Is there a way to disable space trigging autocomplete for M-x?  It'd be nice to still have it, just not bound to space.

I can get something like what I want with:

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map " " nil)
```

Checking the documentation, it looks like space corresponds to minibuffer-complete-word, so I guess I just need to rebind that within the minibuffer key map?

I use Plover steno (https://www.openstenoproject.org/) with Emacs (i.e. mapping key strokes to words/phrases). Plover automatically puts spaces either before or after words. This causes a Catch-22. Using spaces before requires lots of manual adjustments to prevent leading spaces. Using spaces after causes problems with M-x since spaces are interpreted as autocomplete. My preference would be to use spaces after.

Here's what happens with spaces after.  Writing PAO-EU/THOPB for "python" sends `p-i-e-<space>-<backspace>-<backspace>-<backspace>-t-h-o-n` to Emacs. The space is interpreted as autocomplete, so that instead of "python", I get "ython".

Comment: Inasmuch as you have already answered your own question, consider reducing your question to something much more simple / common so that it may help other forum participants in the future; e.g., **Q**:  "*How to disable keyboard shortcut `space` (bound to `minibuffer-complete-word`) when in a minubuffer activated by `M-x`*"  **A**:  `(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map " " nil)`  The information about Plover steno and activating python have no bearing on the question or answer ...

Comment: @lawlist, I appreciate your perspective.  The mention of Plover is to provide the goal, as ESR recommends.  Otherwise, the question runs the risk (without prior knowledge of the answer) of being an XY problem.  I have tried to find a compromise and moved the goal details to the bottom of the question.  Should someone in the future have the same goal but not the vocabulary of "autocompletion within the minibuffer", this should help them find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of space completion within the minibuffer is controlled by the `minibuffer-local-completion-map`.

This can be redefined with something like:

```
;; replace space tab completion with insertion of a space character 
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map " " 'self-insert-command)

;; remap what space was (i.e. `minibuffer-complete-word`) to tab
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map "<tab>" 'minibuffer-complete-word)

;; remap what tab was (i.e. `minibuffer-complete`) to shift-tab
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map "S-<tab>" 'minibuffer-complete)
```

Or, if you use general.el:

```
(general-def :keymaps 'minibuffer-local-completion-map
  "SPC"  'self-insert-command       ;; now inserts a space character 
  "<tab>" 'minibuffer-complete-word ;; previously was space
  "S-<tab>" 'minibuffer-complete    ;; previously was tab
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually better than this:

```lisp
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map " " nil)
```

is this:

```lisp
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map " " 'self-insert-command)
```

It lets `SPC` chars be self-inserting.  That means you can type a space char to match against a completion candidate that contains a space char (duh).  This should, IMHO, be the default behavior for Emacs, but it's not.